# Angular routing in docker and nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:14.15.5 as build-stage
WORKDIR /webapp

COPY package*.json /webapp/
RUN npm ci

COPY ./ /webapp/
RUN npm run build:prod


# copy SPA and serve by nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /webapp/dist/kubernetes-webapp/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I have enabled routing in angular application, and when accessing it on `localhost:4200/myroute` it's working.

But when I run the application in a docker container and acess `localhost:4200/myroute` it returns
`404 Not Found nginx/1.15.12`

The nginx configuration is the default one coming from the `nginx/1.15.12 image`

How am I able to solve the problem and allow angular routing in the docker container with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, The above docker  file will make a build and copy file in ngnix for running your application
(You make a build of angular and expose build folder/static files via nginx server)

1. you are running application on ngnix and on port 80.

- Try opening url `localhost:80` or simply localhost as default port is 80

*when you run angular for development , you use command ng serve and that open on port 4200 and that serve command behind the scene give a server for you to run / develop your project on.

But in your this case you have make a build and you have chosen a server that is running on port 80.